# Choosing Specific Regex Patterns While Excluding Others

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to bookmark following regex lines **in notepad++**:

```
(?<!\d)0*\K(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+|(?!0+(?!\d))\d{1,4})(?!\d)
```

but I don't like following regex lines select with above regex too:

```
\d{4}Q[1-4]
```

How can I do this?

I tried following regular expressions but not working:

```
(?<!\d)0*\K(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+|(?!0+(?!\d))\d{1,4})(?!\d)
(?<!\d)0*\K(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+|(?!0+(?!\d))\d{1,4})(?!\d|.*\b\d{4}Q[1-4]\b)
(?<!\d)0*\K(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+|(?!0+(?!\d))\d{1,4})(?!\d)(?![\s\S]*\b\d{4}Q[1-4]\b)
```

for example in following list I want to bookmark my first regex values but my first regex select last line too (quarter line) and i don't like this!

```
alcatel5,457,850

Samsung

SAMSUNG4,702,078

Sagem

SAGEM2,114,184

NECNEC643,636

1997Q3
/////////////////////////
```

Comment: Could you provide some example inputs with expected and actual matches, so we don't have to create them ourselves?

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride check post again - I provide a list for example

Comment: Add: `(?!.*\d{4}Q[1-4])` in front of your regex.

Comment: who closed question!!!! - i edited post!!

Comment: you look for something like this? `^(?!\d{4}Q[1-4])[^\d\n]+\K[\d,]+`. see at https://regex101.com/r/A5gZud/latest ?

Comment: @PoulBak not working!

Comment: @PoulBak it is closed if you refresh the page. Welcome to stack overflow, OP.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride: Yes, I realized.

Comment: @PubgMobile: "not working" is a very poor feedback, give details.

Comment: @PoulBak I added it to end of my first regex but it still select quarter lines!

Comment: I wrote: " in front of".

Comment: @PoulBak I tried again but this time it select number of quarter! for example 4 in 2000Q4

Comment: Try @DuesserBaest's regex, it seems to work fine.

Comment: Perhaps like this? `(?<!\d)(?:\d{4}Q[1-4]|0+)\b(*SKIP)(*F)|(?<!\d)0*\K(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+|\d{1,4})(?!\d)` https://regex101.com/r/D2xWTd/1

Comment: Do you want to match lines that contain no digits? Like `Samsung` and `Sagem` in your example. What is the purpose of `(?<!\d)0*\K` at the beginning of your regex? You have to given more test cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated as comment try:

```
^(?!\d{4}Q[1-4])[^\d\n]+\K[\d,]+
```

See at regex101.com/r/A5gZud/latest

`^` Asserts position at start of string

`(?!...)` exclude cases when ...

- `\d{4}Q[1-4]` four digits followed by 1 to 4 `Q`

`[^\d\n]+` find anything BUT numbers while not skipping a line ...

`\K` ... and keep this out of the match

`[\d,]+` match digits and `,`

Answer (score 0):

With Notepad++ you can do a multi-step process.

1. Use the big RegEx and mark lines including those that are unwanted.
2. Invert the marking, use menu => **Search** => **Bookmark** => **Inverse bookmarks**. Now unwanted lines are marked.
3. Mark the remaining unwanted lines with the RegEx `\d{4}Q[1-4]`. Now all the unwanted lines are bookmarked.
4. Invert the marking, again use menu => **Search** => **Bookmark** => **Inverse bookmarks**. Now only the wanted lines are marked.